# What are the drawbacks of implementing Web Api using inline handler methods of razor pages

Tags: asp.net-core, razor-pages

As Razor pages can have inline handler methods and pages can be added to a running website without a full deployment.

```
@page
@{
   public void OnGet()
   {
   }
   public void OnPost()
   {
   }
}
```

Thinking of a case when this dynamic addition to site features is a real plus point. What are some drawbacks (apart from the fact that they are difficult to unit test) of creating Web Api using inline handlers methods?

The idea is to make the app more feature friendly where features to existing API or pages can be added on the fly and deployed quickly.

For example, in a CMS where plugins or APIs could be added to a running website without even a restart?